# Show which field the term was found in?

Tags: low-search

In the search results, is there a way to show which custom field a search term was found in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The search index is a big text field per entry, containing all searchable fields. This is what makes the keyword searches fast. However, that also means there is no info as to what specific field contained the keywords. It's totally possible that, for keywords that contain more than one word, the terms are found in multiple fields.